# Regex to match numeric values within parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex to match the each of the numeric values within parentheses.

Here is a link to a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tkQP8z/1) which I have been using for testing.

For instance with a String:

> At present there are no approved therapies to directly target NRAS activating mutations. However, N-Ras activation may predict sensitivity to inhibitors of the Raf/MEK/ERK, PI3K/Akt, and other downstream pathways **(23274911, 22392911, 21993244)**. The MEK inhibitors trametinib and cobimetinib (in combination with vemurafenib) have been FDA-approved for BRAF V600E- and V600K-mutant melanoma, and are currently being studied in clinical trials in solid tumors and hematologic malignancies **(22663011, 25265494)**. Several preclinical studies have suggested that combinations of MEK inhibitors with inhibitors of other downstream molecules, such as PI3K, eIF4A, and Plk1, result in synergistic growth inhibition in NRAS-mutant melanoma in vitro and in vivo **(19492075)**.

I would like to match each of the values shown in bold.  I am currently using the following

```
Pattern citationPattern = Pattern.compile("(.?\()(\\d+)");
        Matcher match = citationPattern.matcher(treatmentApproach);
```

and am able to get up to match each of first values within the parentheses.  How can I extend it for the cases where there are more than one value within the parentheses.  For example **(22663011, 25265494)**. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could pull all values inside the `()`s then iterate over that result. https://regex101.com/r/tkQP8z/4 Then maybe java has a CSV parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just pull the matches from between the literal `(` and `)`. Something like,

```
Pattern citationPattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher match = citationPattern.matcher(treatmentApproach);
while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

Comment: Your regex is greedy; it will match all of `(a, b) unwanted (c, d)`. Change `.*` (greedy) to `.*?` (reluctant)

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks. Was tired.

Comment: Still tired it would seem :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a pattern like this: `[\(|, ](\d+)[, \)]`

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/hoggh0/1

This finds any number between `[open brackets or ", "]` and `[close brackets or ", "]`

The only way this would fall over is if you had numbers in the text that are between comments but not between brackets and wanted to exclude them. This would include them.

Answer (score 0):

`"(\([0-9]+([, ]*[0-9])*\))"` might be what you need. At least it's working here: https://regex101.com/r/tkQP8z/5.